Display prompt on carplay device if user is not logged in App on phone, react native iOS swift
This is my first project in React-Native that too with CarPlay.
Now the code is already done by some other team.
My first task here is, whenever I open CarPlay app, I need to check if the user is logged in or not inside app on Phone.
I have created bridging and send the value from React-Native side to Swift. But I am not getting in which method I should validate that if user is logged In or not.
The code I did so far is.
In CarPlayBridge.Swift file
@objc func setCarplayParameter(_ isAuthenticated: Bool){
    print("if user is authenticated : \(isAuthenticated)")
    var isAuth: Bool = isAuthenticated
  }

In my Config.swift file
var isAuthenticated : Bool = false

In CarPlaySceneDelegate.Swift
if(isAuthenticated){
        //true : go to dashbaord
      }else{
        //false : show alert
      }

In CaRPlayBridge.m file
 RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(setCarplayParameter:
         (bool *)isAuthenticated
     )

In my Index.tsx
  useEffect(() => {
    NativeModules.CarPlayBridge.setCarplayParameter(isAuthenticate);
  }, [isAuthenticate]);

How can I check that value I am receiving CarPlayBridge.Swift for isAuthenticated is correct, and where I should write the code to check that user is logged in or not when he open CarPlay app on his CarPlay device?
